# Shopify Slate v1 starter theme grid

Tags: shopify

Hi I am new to Shopify theme development.

I am using Slate V1 to create a new theme from scratch. I have it all setup and running fine with a test store.

I understand that this is a starter theme but there are a bunch of grid classes such as: grid__item small--one-half etc

But there doesn't seem to be any scss that controls the grid system. Am I missing something in my install or does this need to be added separately?